# Gradle 3.5 how to set jar baseName from archiveBaseName in allproject

Tags: java, gradle, jar, java-8, build.gradle

I have the following **allprojects** directive in my root project `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {

    dependencies {
        testCompile("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
    }

    jar {
        baseName = project.archivesBaseName
        from files(project.subprojects.sourceSets.main.output)

        manifest {
            attributes(
                    "Created-By": vendor,
                    "Specification-Title": jar.archiveName,
                    "Specification-Version": version,
                    "Specification-Vendor": vendor,
                    "Implementation-Title": jar.baseName,
                    "Implementation-Version" : version,
                    "Implementation-Vendor": vendor,
            )
        }
    }

}
```

In every sub project, I redefine in their `build.gradle` the `archiveBaseName` but all my JAR archives get produced with the `baseName` of the `archiveBaseName` of the root project.

Is there a way to dynamically create my archives name base on my override of `archiveBaseName` ?

Comment: Hey, Dimitri:  I'm trying to set an archiveBaseName for a location of my local .m2 repository.  Can you take a look at my question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57210699/1735836   Maybe you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the `allprojects` closure is evaluated, the subprojects build scripts are not yet evaluated and thus you don't see the overridden value but the original one.

You have to delay the configuration of the `Jar` task you are doing with `afterEvaluate`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the exact synthax ? I managed in a different way by creating a `gradle.properties` file in all of my subproject.

Comment: Of course I do, just wrap the `jar {}` in `afterEvaluate {}`

Comment: Well, you have to split it into two halfes, one that sets the basename and one that sets the manifest attributes, otherwise your overwriting will not work.

Comment: And the `from` line looks very much like raping of Gradle and not like a clean build, but if it works for you, fine. ;-)

Comment: why do you say that ? They use it in the shadow plugin : https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/ShadowJavaPlugin.groovy#L40

Comment: No they don't. They include the output of the project, not output of subprojects. You should add project dependencies on the subprojects instead and thus get the JARs built by the subprojects as dependencies. If it works for you, it's fine, Gradle doesn't give you the flexibility to do what you want without a reason. It just feels a bit awkward to me to include compile output of a subproject like that. :-)