# how to set archiveBaseName for local .m2 repository

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, alias

I'm trying to upgrade a dependency to a project that will ultimately become a dependency to my project.  I've made the upgrade and I want to test it locally before I put it out on the repo to be used.  I'm learning Gradle and a few Google searches showed me how to add the project to the settings.gradle file.  But the dependency project uses aliases for their dependencies (see build.gradle below).

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':TransportImpl'
```

Changed to:

```
include ':TransportImpl', ':jeromq'
project(':jeromq').projectDir = new File("../zeromq/jeromq")
```

**build.gradle**

```
//project.ext.set("JEROMQ", 'THIRD-PARTY:jeromq:0.4.2')
project.ext.set("JEROMQ", ':jeromq')
```

If I uncomment the original line (shown commented above), because that apk is in the repo it gets recognized.  I'm guessing that this only works for external libraries.

Other things I have tried:

```
//project.ext.set("JEROMQ", 'C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/THIRD_PARTY/jeromq/0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/jeromq-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT-jeromq.jar')
//project.ext.set("JEROMQ", 'C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\THIRD_PARTY\\jeromq\\0.5.1\\jeromq-0.5.1-jeromq.jar')
//implementation filetree(dir: 'C:\\Users\\username\\.m2\\repository\\THIRD_PARTY\\jeromq\\0.5.1', include:['jeromq-0.5.1-jeromq.jar'])
```

Can anyone give me a tip on how I can assign a variable that points to the local repository and use that variable to set an archiveBaseName?

---

**New Information:**

gradle.build for our jeromq project

```
apply plugin : 'maven'
apply plugin : 'maven-publish'

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext {
    // Nexus paths
    nexusUrl='https://nexus.path'
    Releases='/Private_Releases'

    nexusUsername = project.findProperty("nexusUsername") ?: (System.getenv("NEXUS_USERNAME") ?: "user_name"
    nexusPassword = project.findProperty("nexusPassword") ?: (System.getenv("NEXUS_PASSWORD") ?: "password")

    // Project versions
    jeromqVersion = "0.5.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

allprojects {
    // Read only repositories for dependencies; this should never be used to publish
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The project that uses it as a dependency finds it using the following from its build.gradle file:

```
// Create aliases for dependencies
project.ext.set("EASY_MOCK", 'Test:easymock:3.5.1')
project.ext.set("OBJENESIS", 'Test:objenesis:2.6')
// **************** HERE ***************************
// THIRD-PARTY is configured to look on the nexus server
project.ext.set("JEROMQ", 'THIRD-PARTY:jeromq:0.4.2') ... or 0.5.1 or 0.5.1-SNAPSHOT ...

allprojects {
  // Read only repositories for dependencies; this should never be used to publish
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
//      maven {
//          // trying to add my local repo, 
//          // BUT this still does not change where THIRD-PARTY is pointing to
//          url 'file://C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/THIRD_PARTY/jeromq/0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/jeromq-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT-jeromq.jar'
//      }
    maven {
      name 'ReleasesName'
      url "$nexusUrl$ReleasesName
      }
    }
    maven {
      name 'ReleasesNameSnapshots'
      url "$nexusUrl$ReleasesNameSnapshots"

      credentials {
        username "${rootProject.ext.nexusReadOnlyUsername}"
        password "${rootProject.ext.nexusReadOnlyPassword}"
      }
    }
    jcenter {
      url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
```

The only reason I need the alias for that dependency is because it is used in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think what you are trying is completely off.

The build you are trying to include is a Maven build, not a Gradle build, so it is unlikely you can simply treat it as it were a Gradle build.

And even if it were a Gradle build, including it like you did would not be the right way. How you tried it is for including multiple projects of a multi-project build, not including external libraries.

If it were a Gradle build, you would use a composite build, which effectively replaces a declared binary dependency by the build output of a "sub-build". But afair this only works cleanly with a Gradle build.

Why don't you simply `mvn install` your modified jeromq version, add `mavenLocal()` to your dependencies and depend on that just installed version? That would be the usual way for locally testing new Maven built dependencies.

Comment: FINALLY!  After a lot of research I understand your solution (mvn install) is correct.  You are right, I was way off.  I'm learning.  Thank you.